# mysql multiple query based on values

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So, I have a following js and php:

**JS:**

```
var names = jQuery('#name').val();
data : {'action':'AJAX' , name:names },
```

**PHP:**

```
global $wpdb;
$names      = $_POST['name'];
$name    = explode(',', $names);    
$table     = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_name'; 
$RSS = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT number FROM $table WHERE sub_id = $name");
```

So, here is the thing, this `#name` can have multiple values (for example, steve,sean,mike).

I need to do multiple search `WHERE = $name` based on the number of values that I have.

I thought I would explode each value then use them.

However, that's as far as I gotten and not sure how to put a necessary condition in the query.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: use a `WHERE IN` clause for that, i think wordpress also has a prepared statement wrapper use that also

Comment: So something like this? `"SELECT number  FROM $gallery  WHERE sub_id IN ($name)";` ?

Comment: in essence it should be like that but that is unsafe since you're directly using your values into the query statement, you should use prepared statements instead

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but would you be able to show me how to do it using the prepared statement? I am bit lost...

Comment: i don't know if this is intentional, but, shouldn't it be `$names` inside explode instead of `$tags`

Comment: Opps, typo. fixed it.

Comment: you can get familiar with it by checking it here https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb there are plenty of examples using prepared select. here is a nice article https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/wpdb-prepare-in-clause-unknown-placeholders/